# JQuery : How can we filter int from variable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to filter numbers from the variable.

I can show you one example here from the link http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/82r5v/6/

I need to get only numbers from the alert message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `var order = $("#boxes").sortable("toArray");`

to `var order = $("#boxes").sortable("toArray").join(',').replace(/[a-zA-Z]/gi, "");`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/82r5v/13/

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace the box string out of it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/82r5v/10/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
   order[i] = order[i].replace('box', '');
}
```

Comment: Out of interest is there an advantage to using this over the regex method?

Comment: @benedict_w For me, it would be readability. Regex can look and scan as an over-engineered solution to what really amounts to "replace this string with nothing". If you're fluent in Regex, it probably scans just as easily. But I think many of us still consult our resources every single time we use regex. ;-) I like to save it for a situation in which a simple replace isn't good enough.

Comment: I see. Fair enough, I would find the loop extraneous - but horses for courses I suppose. Was wondering if there was some performance reason I didn't know about. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @benedict_w RegEx is comparatively slower than a simple replace. Especially in this scenario, I believe replace is faster than RegEx. There are cases, where you need to use regEx if not you will end up writing a lot of replace functions.

Answer (score 2):

So instead of `box1, box2, box3, box4` you want to see `1,2,3,4`

You can use a regular expression like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/82r5v/11/):

```
var order = $("#boxes").sortable("toArray") + "";
alert(order.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, ''));
```

I also had to append an empty string to `order` because it wasn't being recognized as a string object even though the jQuery documentation says it should be when you call `sortable("toArray")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove all non-digits from the string
'box1'.replace(/\D/g, ''); // => '1'
// Same, but try to make the string a number
Number('box1'.replace(/\D/g, '')); // => 1
// Shorthand for making an object a number (+o is the same as Number(o))
+'box1'.replace(/\D/g, ''); // => 1
// parseInt(s) works if the number is at the beginning
parseInt('1box'); // => 1
// but not if it occurs later
parseInt('box1'); // => NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using regular expressions something like this:

```
`alert(order.join(',').match(/\d/g));`
```

To return the array as numbers.

(`\d` matches all digits, `g` signifies a global match wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it by using regular expressions - http://jsfiddle.net/holodoc/82r5v/14/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var arrValuesForOrder = ["2", "1", "3", "4"];
    var ul = $("#boxes"),
        items = $("#boxes li.con");

    for (var i = arrValuesForOrder[arrValuesForOrder.length - 1]; i >= 0; i--) {
        // arrValuesForOrder[i] element to move
        // i = index to move element at
        ul.prepend(items.get(arrValuesForOrder[i] - 1));
    }

$("#boxes").sortable({
    handle : '.drag',
    update: function() {
        var order = $("#boxes").sortable("toArray");
        var sorted = [];
        $.each(order, function(index, value){
           sorted.push(value.match(/box(\d+)/)[1]);                
        })
        alert(sorted);
    }
});

});
```